# Phonegap selecting multiple images from gallery/camera

Tags: image, cordova, photo-gallery

I'm using the latest version of Phonegap and trying to build an app where users can select and upload multiple images from their gallery. Problem is, users may need to select tons of images, similar to the facebook app.
Does phonegap allow this, or is this functionality that can only be done in an native app?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220251/phonegap-cordova-select-multiple-photos/21351913#21351913)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know this has to be done as a custom plugin.  The core phonegap plugins do not allow for this.

My company has written a plugin that allows multiple images to be selected for iOS and Android.  It can be found here: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

Comment: Thank you!. Just a suggestion: On Android would raise this error  (caused by cordova bug): No installed handlers for this URL when using 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL'https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6345. To avoid this you should include this plugin org.apache.cordova.file-system-roots or update the file plugin to version  1.0.2 (dev version).You could include this information in your project!. Hope it helps other people.

Comment: Hi how to convert to base64 string image? instead of return file uri