# phoneGap: select audio file from device and upload

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phoneGap. I am creating a dummy app to upload an audio file from iOS/android device on local server. So I was wondering if there is a way to open the audio gallery and select the required audio file to upload. Similar to an image gallery.

Is it possible to open audio list and select necessary audio file? If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you cannot reach the pictures and audio files stored in the media gallery. Therefore, you may need to implement your own native plugin and call the appropriate methods from your JavaScript code.

You can capture audio/image by using Capture plugin of Phonegap. Check this out [Capture Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture)

You can perform basic File operations as well. Check this out [File Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

For your situation, you have to implement native interface which can be accessed by your JavaScript code. This would be an alternative way for it. If you desire to create your own plugin, please have a look at [Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). This might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have implemented [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220251/phonegap-cordova-select-multiple-photos/21351913#21351913) using file plugin which will iterate through all the folders recursively to find all the image (created this as I needed multi selection approach which is not directly provided by cordova) . You can modify the extension of image (search) i.e png,jpeg etc with audio extension. 
With this code you will get the path of audio files and you can make use of filetransfer to upload it on server

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you For your answer but can you send me complete code ?

Comment: You can check the link embedded in answer for getting the files... You can create your own container for displaying it