# How to access audio fle and upload to server in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

i have one query like i want access to all audio file in phone gap ios and want to upload to server, so any one know how to do get all mp3 files and get upload.
we should need to create a plugin for that .

Comment: Refer answer of Divesh Salian you will get idea- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527325/phonegap-select-audio-file-from-device-and-upload

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you require to create a new plugin. The existing File and File Transfer API should work in your case unless you have more requirements other than the ones stated here.

Use the file API to iterate over all the files in the app.

```
function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        console.log(entries[i].name);
           //Check if the file is in mp3 format. If it is in mp3 format, trigger file upload.

    }
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
}

// Get a directory reader
var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

// Get a list of all the entries in the directory
directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
```

Then use the file upload API to upload the files to the server.

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```