# counting images in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am working on `PhoneGap/Cordova` different features now I guess is there some way to count the images that present in mobile gallery. I search different place but can;t get any help yet.
So is there any function or hint through which I can count the images from gallery

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220251/phonegap-cordova-select-multiple-photos/21351913#21351913) in function wearedone u will get the count of image

Comment: I tried this but when i call function app closes without showing anything @DiveshSalian

Comment: do u get ny error in logcat ???

Comment: `JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1`
   This line and then `VM aborting`

Comment: which version of cordova ???

Comment: cordova version 2.9.0

Comment: Try adding console.log in between for loops and check I have tested this version 3.0

Comment: Hi did you have any idea that how much images can handle this program/
Because previously when I ran that program in mobile with more than 1000 images (6 GB+) than it crashed but now in emulator with 2 images it run smoothly and give result correctly. So do you have any idea about that @DiveshSalian

Comment: I have tested only wid 100 image

Comment: Thanks. i will test that with different no. of images and on different device then tell you exact limit.
Anyways that piece of code is awesome and work like charm :)

Comment: Glad that it helped u